# Cumulative Distribution Function For Normals

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

**Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $N(0,1)$ random variables such that $X_2=-X_1$ if $|X_1|<1$ and $X_2=X_1$ otherwise. Obtain the cumulative distribution function of $X_1+X_2$ represented in the form(s) of cumulative distribution function of a standard normal variable.**

I get $P(X_1+X_2<z)=\Phi (z/2)$ if $|z|>2$. But what about the case $|z|<2$? I would like to get convinced that my working is right. What I think will happen is, if $-2<z<2$ then $P(X_1+X_2<z)=P(X_1+X_2<-2)+P(-2<X_1+X_2<z)=\Phi (-1)+P(-2<0<z)=\Phi (-1)+0.5$

This is because $0$ is either less than or greater than $z$ which is a real number. So $P(-2<0<z)=P(0<z)=0.5$.

Is the reasoning correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider: What are $F(-2)$ and $F(2)$? What's $P(X_1+X_2=0)$? What's $P(-2<X_1+X_2<0)$? What's $P(0<X_1+X_2<2)$? If you can answer those, you should be able to write down the whole CDF by inspection.

Comment: What do you denote by $F$, please state more clearly.
$P(X_1+X_2=0)=P(-1<X_1<1)=2\Phi (1)-1$.
$P(-2<X_1+X_2<0)=$ my doubt. Same goes for $P(0<X_1+X_2<2)$.
But as I said, the event $X_1+X_2$ between 0 and 2 occurs ONLY when $X_1+X_2=0$ i.e. the probability of this event is $P(-1<X_1<1)$ or less. Need some help here.

Comment: $F$ is the cdf of $X_1+X_2$. You should have no doubt what $P(X_1+X_2=0)$ is. Under what circumstances is $X_2=-X_1$ ... (which is the same as $X_1+X_2=0$)?

Comment: $P(X_1+X_2=0)=2\Phi (1)-1$ : is this not correct?

Comment: So can you figure out the other quantities I mentioned now?

Comment: Umm, I guess $P(-2<X_1+X_2<0)$ is not clear to me. Would it be correct to say that $P(-2<X_1+X_2<0)=P(0<X_1+X_2<2)=(2\Phi (1)-1)/2=\Phi (1)-1/2$?

Comment: What is $p_1=P(X_1+X_2<-2)$? By symmetry, what is $p_2=P(X_1+X_2>2)$? You also have $p_0=P(X_1+X_2=0)$. Given those, what is $p_0+p_1+p_2$? Hence, what is $P(-2<X_1+X_2<0)$?